# less -z option: the manpage refers to it, but does not document it

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, less

Simply put, what does the `-z` flag to `less` do? In the prezto (zsh shell) config, the `$LESS` env var is set with flags and the last one is `-z-4`.

What does this do? Is there a version of a less manpage somewhere that has this?

Answer (score 2):

> `-[z]n` or `--window=n`
>
> Changes  the  default scrolling window size to `n` lines. The default is one screenful. The `z` and `w` commands can also be used to change the window size.  The "z" may be omitted for compatibility with some versions of `more`. If the number `n` is negative, it indicates `n` lines less than the current screen size. For example, if the screen is 24 lines, `-z-4` sets the scrolling window to 20 lines. If the screen is resized to 40 lines, the scrolling window automatically changes to 36 lines.

Source: [man page for `less`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/less/) (Linux 2.6).

Note: my tests indicate that `0` is treated as "negative" in this context. The relevant fragment should say "if the number `n` is nonpositive…".

Comment: Ah okay. it's impossible to find this by simply grepping for `-z`.